# Proverbs 1:14 compared to John 13:29

Tags: proverbs

Proverbs 1:14 says

> Throw in your lot with us, we shall all have one purse

but John 13:29 says Judas had the common purse.  Surely Jesus would not have allowed a common purse among the disciples if Proverbs says not to!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In context, Proverbs 1 here is talking about joining with sinful men, plundering and gambling. It is a completely unrelated passage of Scripture.

Here it is in-context with the surrounding passages:

> **Warning Against the Invitation of Sinful Men**
>
> 8 Listen, my son, to your father’s instruction
>       and do not forsake your mother’s teaching. 9 They are a garland to grace your head
>       and a chain to adorn your neck.
>
> 10 My son, if sinful men entice you,
>       do not give in to them. 11 If they say, “Come along with us;
>       let’s lie in wait for innocent blood,
>       let’s ambush some harmless soul; 12 let’s swallow them alive, like the grave,
>       and whole, like those who go down to the pit; 13 we will get all sorts of valuable things
>       and fill our houses with plunder; 14 cast lots with us;
>       we will all share the loot”— 15 my son, do not go along with them,
>       do not set foot on their paths; 16 for their feet rush into evil,
>       they are swift to shed blood. 17 How useless to spread a net
>       where every bird can see it! 18 These men lie in wait for their own blood;
>       they ambush only themselves! 19 Such are the paths of all who go after ill-gotten gain;
>       it takes away the life of those who get it.

Clearly, the condemnation is in pooling your resources with sinful people, not just pooling your resources altogether.

To try to link the two is a logic flaw. It would be like claiming that 2 Corinthians 6:14 says not to be yoked to (joined to, in a partnership with) *anyone*.

> Do not be yoked together with unbelievers. For what do righteousness
>   and wickedness have in common? Or what fellowship can light have with
>   darkness?

2 Corinthians 6:14 is speaking only of being yoked to ***unbelievers***, just as the Proverb you cited is clearly about joining with evil.

There are some [basic, commonly accepted rules for reading, understanding, and applying Scripture](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/from-a-fundamentalist-viewpoint-what-does-it-mean-to-take-the-bible-literally/9962#9962). One of them is not taking a single verse out of context with the surrounding text, intended audience, and meanings of words/statements at the time it was written. In context, it's clear there is no conflict here.

Comment: Excellent answer generally, but the rules you link to are not "commonly accepted". They are specific to biblical literalism, which is a minority view within Christianity. Of course not taking a single verse out of context certainly *is* commonly accept, but the others - not so much.