# How and when do I take God's word literally?

Tags: moses, literalism, 1-corinthians

Every time I talk to a non-believer, they reference several things that they think make their argument stronger.

When I talk about what God says for us not and not to do, they bring up things like "God tells us not to shave our heads," to which I say that God was speaking to people like Moses and the principal of faith comes in; if you follow God, no matter what he says, then great things will happen. (The passages referenced are found in Corinthians, around chapter 11)

How do I explain that God is often meteorically talented (if and only if I'm right here), and that sometimes we don't need to take EVERYTHING he says literally?

How do I tell if he is telling something that should be taken word for word?

Comment: Please help us define the scope by telling us the denomination which you'd like to have your answer focused on.  Denominations and even groups within the denomination may have distinctly different (but correct) answers.  There is no single and agreeable answer to your question.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about Mosaic/OT laws?

Comment: Related  http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/from-a-fundamentalist-viewpoint-what-does-it-mean-to-take-the-bible-literally

Comment: Christianity. I'm talking about Christianity specifically.

Comment: @DavidStratton i red that link but it is different because yours talks about if you UNDERSTAND the bible.

Comment: @ilarsona Christianity is not monolithic. Asking for all of Christianity is out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically if you are talking to a non-believer that is not a **Jew** - He is not under the **Law of Moses** before of after **Christ Jesus**. He could turn xtian and start to **LITERALLY** uphold the Law of Moses but that would [curse](http://biblehub.com/galatians/3-10.htm) him. **Xtians** are not under the Law of Moses.

Romans 3 and Galatians 3 explains that xtians are not under the law of Moses anymore:
1) everyone sinned under the Law of Moses
2) there is not even ONE righteous person

Usually God would count on that **one righteous** person to save mankind and avoid God's wrath. Thus Christ Jesus, to save mankind AND show how to UPHOLD the Law of Moses thru **faith**.

Romans 3:30 NET

> Since God is one, he will justify the circumcised by faith and the
>   uncircumcised through faith

This is where your **denomination** or **nondenominational** of choice comes in: 
To show you how to UPHOLD the Law of Moses through FAITH IN CHRIST JESUS.

Titus 3:4 NET

> But “when the kindness of God our Savior and his love for mankind
>   appeared, he saved us not by works of righteousness that we have done
>   but on the basis of his mercy

thanks for reading