# The use of the term "scripture" in the Christian Bible

Tags: biblical-basis, exegesis, canon

Something I've been curious about for some time. There is a verse stating that "scripture" is the inerrant word of the Christian god:

> "All Scripture is God-breathed and is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness". 2 Timothy 2:16

However, it doesn't go into specifics about what "scripture" is. At the time that this scripture was written (around the [first century](http://catholic-resources.org/Bible/Paul-Disputed.htm)), the modern New Testament canon had not yet been established.

How is the connection made between the use of the term "scripture" in certain passages, and the compilation of various writings currently called the Bible?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE! This has actually been asked before - [What Does 'Scripture' Mean in NT Writing?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/12428/4188)

Comment: @RyanFrame Oh thanks, should I delete it, or just wait for it to get marked as duplicate?