# What's the justification of eternal torture in hell?

Tags: hell

Most of the world ratified the [United Nations Convention against Torture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Convention_Against_Torture).

*Can the belief in hell be justified against the Convention in those countries?*

The punishment is to encourage and enforce proper behavior (not eternal) or to protect potential victims (no torture, see the Convention). So for better explanation of the question:

*What is the meaning of eternal torture?*

The satisfying answer should justify general christian insight without counterquestions, without metaphores, without implicit assumptions, without solipsism and without twisting of meanings.

Comment: Welcome to the site by the way. I hope you don't take my vote to close as a judgement on the quality or content of your question. It's a valid question. Unfortunately it's already been addressed here, stated in various ways. The question I linked to is only one of many. For other similar ones, search the site for "loving God Hell" and you'll get several variations of "How could a loving God create hell?"

Comment: BTW, I assume from your username that you'd consider yourself an atheist. I'd like to reassure you that [atheists are welcome here](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/493/are-questions-from-atheists-welcome-here), so long as you follow the [guidelines](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [don't misunderstand the purpose of the site](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/1381#1381).

Comment: FYI: Not all christians believe in eternal hell. Annihilationism is the belief that those who don't make it to heaven are destroyed completely.

Comment: As far as I am aware, God is not a signatory to any United Nations convention.

Comment: @DavidStratton: no problem, David. But the linked question is different: it asks about *suffering*, in the explanation is *punishment* and the answer is about *separating*, while I ask about *torture*: these are four different things. I was expecting the misunderstanding, therefore I added the last paragraph, with all the respect. I'd like to focus on the *torture*. Thanks for invitation, it would be nice to reopen.

Comment: @DJClayworth: of course Yahweh isn't. But the question stands *if the belief in hell can be justified against the Convention* due to the torture. I understand that it is not a pleasant question for christians who believe in loving god, but please note the last paragraph: *without twisting of meaning*. I don't want to condemn christian faith, so I ask.

Comment: You understand that on this site, all the answers you are going to get will be from a Christian perspective?

Comment: This question needs some serious language clean-up; I'm not sure I should bother, because it also seems like it probably should be closed.

Comment: @DJClayworth That's why I'm asking here: I don't want own opinion confirmation, but still I hope for non-evasive answer.

Comment: @Chelonian please do so, English is not my primary language. Your comment is about 25% length of the question.

Comment: My comment took 12 seconds to dash off; editing your question well would take 9 minutes.  I'm having trouble with it, because I can't be sure quite what you mean.

Comment: @humanist I can understand what's in your mind, your user name explains it. I gave an answer with a different view but I have no idea others will agree to it or not.

Comment: The question "Can the belief in hell be justified against the Convention ...?" presupposes that the convention prohibits believing that torture takes place. As far as I know, it only prohibits torture, not the belief that torture takes place.

Comment: Why would God sending someone to hell be classified as torture?

Comment: You're going to spend eternity with people who are like you. This sounds _perfectly_ just to me. If you don't want to spend eternity with people who are going to spend that eternity tearing into you (while you tear into them with an equally insane fervor), then don't be one of those people.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Hell was originally created for Satan and his fallen angels

> Matthew 25:41 (NIV) “Then he will say to those on his left, ‘Depart
>   from me, you who are cursed, into the ***eternal fire prepared for the
>   devil and his angels***.

We always have this misconception that God created hell to torture who do not believe Him or follow His commandments. I would argue that this is ***wrong***! When God created Adam and Eve, His intention was to have a good fellowship and love relationship with them. We know that Satan fell before the creation of Adam. Hell was prepared for Satan and his fellow fallen angels.

> Luke 8:31 (NIV) And they begged Jesus repeatedly not to order them to
>   go into the Abyss.

The Devil and his angels are allowed to dominate and work on earth until their appointed time has arrived. The Devil is also called the prince of this world which indicates that he is the ruler of this world ([see John 14:30](http://biblehub.com/john/14-30.htm)). When Jesus was on earth, whenever the demons saw Him, they were terrified, thinking that their time is up!

> Matthew 8:29 (NIV) “What do you want with us, Son of God?” they
>   shouted. “Have you come here to torture us before the appointed time?”

### God has no responsibility for the lost souls

Whoever does not believe in Jesus Christ is not allowed to enter Heaven where God dwells. They will be thrown out of the Kingdom of God to where Satan lives, which is hell. Satan is not merciful like God, there is no love in him, he is rebellious, he loves to torture people, he loves destruction. God has no responsibility for anything that happen to those who are in hell.

### Satan and his angles are the one who torture the souls

There is no direct scripture support for this but the scripture never say that God is responsible for the torture. You may go to http://www.youtube.com and search for the testimonies of those who visited Hell. You will usually find that there is no God in Hell nor his holy angles. The angels of Satan are the one who are torturing the souls in Hell. This is not scriptural but I'm just giving a real life example.

Comment: There are some personal bias in the answer, but at least I can't find any internal inconsistency. At least to the point if Yahweh is responsible for hell. It's rather philosophical: is parent responsible for his child? Is A-bomb creator responsible for Hiroshima? Is knife manufacturer responsible for murder? If anyone won't find any internal inconsistency, I may accept this as an answer.

Comment: @humanist I made this answer with a full knowledge that people won't agree. I have a different way of viewing things. I want to view God as just and rational. Not just playing around with His creation. If you want to show that you have a different view, accept the answer, just for the sake of showing your agreement. People might still downvote this but I'm reluctant to remove this post.

Comment: I still don't understand why God is unable to defend the eternally tortured souls against Satan: if God is omnipotent, then why does He allow these people to receive eteral torture that they do not deserve?

Comment: @AndersonGreen they do not deserve? How many in Hell do you think are there who deserves to go to Heaven or are judged unfairly by God?

Comment: For example, it would seem unjust for an atheist to be tortured eternally (on account of their religious beliefs alone) if they discovered a cure for cancer (or made some similarly heroic accomplishment). I don't think anyone would deserve infinite torture for a sin that was not infinite: no one can be infinitely good or infinitely evil, so how can they deserve eternal reward or eternal punishment?

Comment: @AndersonGreen Does God need your good works? Is God happy when someone discovered something useful?

Comment: I would hope so: would a non-believer deserve eternal torture if they had lived an otherwise virtuous life?

Comment: @AndersonGreen That is why Jesus commanded us to preach the gospel to the whole world.

Answer (score 5):

Even though I believe this has been answered elsewhere, I'll go ahead and answer this based on the comments to the original question.

***Disclaimer:***

Before I do, I need to remind everyone of the narrow scope of this site:  We are not focused on proving any particular thing to be true.  We focus solely on what the teachings are.  As such it would be against site guidelines to answer whether the eternal punishment in Hell is true, or if God was justified to create an eternal place of torment.  We can only answer what is taught within Christianity.

---

I'm going to answer this from the standard protestant [Apologetics](http://carm.org/dictionary-apologetics) answer, which shares common themes across denominational boundaries.

The question here, as focused by the comments is "can the belief in hell be justified against the U.N. convention of disallowing torture".

The obvious answer here is the one that God gave to Job when Job questioned him about his misery.  "Who are we to question God?"

> **Job 38:4  (KJV)**
>
> Where were you when I laid the foundations of the earth? declare, if
>   you have understanding.

As explained by Matthew **[Henry's Concise Commentary](http://biblehub.com/job/38-4.htm)**

> For the humbling of Job, God here shows him his ignorance, even
>   concerning the earth and the sea. As we cannot find fault with God's
>   work, so we need not fear concerning it. The works of his providence,
>   as well as the work of creation, never can be broken; and the work of
>   redemption is no less firm, of which Christ himself is both the
>   Foundation and the Corner-stone. The church stands as firm as the
>   earth.

In other words, God does not have to justify torture.  (More on this later in the answer)

***But that's not what you asked***.  What you specifically is *how we humans can justify the belief in Hell* when the U.N. has condemned it.

Again - short answer.  We believe it because God said it's true.  As pointed out by God in his discussion with Job (And by DJClayworth's comment), God is sovereign.  ***God doesn't answer to us, we answer to Him***.

We believe (at least most Christians do) that the Bible is God's [inspired, inerrant Word](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/from-a-fundamentalist-standpoint-what-does-the-phrase-inspired-infallible-in).

*Side note: Why we believe that would be the basis of a hundred other questions already answered on this site.  And to make a distinction, that we accept this is not an implicit assumption, it is an established doctrine.  Remember, we are not here to teach what is True, just what Christianity teaches, and it is undeniable that Christianity teaches that the Bible is God's word.  Any attempt to steer this into a direction of [whether it really is God's word is strictly not allowed in the site guidelines](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/what-should-we-tell-people-on-our-about-page-that-says-how-we-are-different/1809#1809).*

---

**Main answer:**

So that's it in a nutshell.  We justify our belief because we trust God's word, and His word says it is so. We do not believe that God is accountable to the U.N. or any other organization/being, etc.

---

**Extra credit**

Addressing your qualifiers:

> The satisfying answer should justify general christian insight without
>   counterquestions, without metaphores, without implicit assumptions,
>   without solipsism and without twisting of meanings.

While I'm at it, however, I'll point out that the underlying assumptions in the question are that:

1. God isn't real
2. The existence of Hell is immoral

In other words, the belief that we need to justify this is based on the assumption that God is a man-made construct.  That we, as the group who believes in this made-up being, are responsible for introducing the idea of eternal torture.   And that we must somehow answer for it or justify it.  That is, in itself an "implicit assumption".  It is quite impossible to have an opinion on anything without implicit assumptions.  We all have them.  We all have a set of glasses through which we see the world, and a base set of implicit assumptions that color our perceptions.

The very idea that "God is not real" generally springs  the idea that "I won't believe it if it's not proven to me".  In other words, if you can't prove that god exists, to my own satisfaction, then I don't believe He does.  Tracing this back further, the root assumption that leads to this is that you are trusting only in your own intellect, mind, and reasoning process.  This is the very [solipsism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism) you sought to ban in any "satisfying answer".

*To bar implicit assumptions and solipsism in an answer to a question that is dripping with them shows a bit of a double standard.*  But at least I think I avoided the metaphor.

Likely, however, this won't be a "satisfying answer".  If you were hoping for someone to come with proof that Hell is justified, I'm sorry, this is the wrong site.  We don't focus on what's true, but rather what's taught.  You may wish to go to a site dedicated to such things, but this isn't it.

Comment: Thank you for putting quite lot of effort into the answer, David. Jesus wasn't having problems answering to ordinary people anytime. He was using metaphors and counterquestions, but sometimes he was able to reply without these "dirty tricks". I respect christian beliefs that Yahweh doesn't need to respond us, however he can. The possible answers are yes or no or I don't know - with optional explanation. I ensure you I don't have those underlying assumptions. However, I see contradict in Yahweh beeing good and hell's torture. How christians deal with this?

Comment: Which goes back to my original set of comments. The question  "How could a loving God create hell?" has already been answered in various guises on this site. The underlying question, as you just pointed out, is this.  Which is why I voted to close as a duplicate in the first place.

Comment: Please don't assume such things. I don't see the existence of hell itself to be contradictory to divine attributes. But the eternal torture seems to be contradictory to the goodness and the response "God is not obligated to answer this" looks like an evasive answer of wrongdoer. Is Yahweh really evasive here?

Comment: Hell is implicitly a place of suffering. So if you accept Hell as being consistent with the divine, you should have no trouble with people suffering in it. Also God no more *has* to give you an answer that fit in with your conditions than you have to tell your five-year old why he should pick up his room in terms that satisfy his conditions.

Comment: @DJClayworth Hell is the place of suffering and punishment (see the hell tag) which should enforce proper behavior (see wiki definition). If it is enforced (or potential victims protected), no more suffering is necessary. If someone change, humanists always forgive anything. Jesus (in bible) too. Eternal punishment means that Yahweh doesn't forgive, which would be very bad of him. The accepted answer claims that hell is not under Yahweh's control, which is probably not christian mainstream, but at least it is consistent with Yahweh's goodness.

Comment: @DJClayworth You don't need to answer valid question from five-year old - at the price of losing his/her respect. If Yahweh exists (we assume it here) and if he is superior, he still needs to earn respect - this is not blasphemy, this is justice - respect is always earned, or it is fake. And respect must be earned from everyone. I as a teacher must earn respect from every student, even the least talented.

Comment: @humanist this debate in comments goes against StackExchange guidelines. If you wish to continue, do so in chat, nit on the main site.

Answer (score 1):

In the **literal** sense, there is no justification in eternal torture in hell.

The bible is absolutely steeped in symbolism, but gives plenty of "keys" to understanding the symbolisms.

Ecclesiastes 9:5 - Dead are unconscious.

Revelation 20:11-15 - Gehenna (Means *second* death...so where was the *first* death?)

*Humans seems to like this idea of punishing by fire*, but God states **such an idea does not even come up into his heart**:

[Jeremiah 7:31- 32](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=jeremiah%207:31-%2032)

The above account states that this manner of reasoning (punishment by fire) was directly inspired by pagan worship Jeremiah 7:30, and obviously it still is.

---

This torment-in-hellfire is an unending debate, but in the bible trees talk, animals with seven heads eat prostitutes, horses are ridden in heaven, locusts sting people. Its certainly not a boring read. But truly, its obvious **our God-given intelligent minds were meant to perceive things beyond the strictly literal** (John 6:56).

Most importantly religions and prominent leaders have always twisted things to get obedience by morbid fear, but the mind of God is very different: Matthew 11:30, 1 John 4:8.

And before it even goes as far as permanent death, there is always a kind hand out to pull us back from the proverbial fire: [Job 33:22-29](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job%2033:22-29&version=AMP), Jude 1:23.

With all things considered - eternal punishment by fire (everlasting death) is a strong motivator to turn around given by a loving God, even if a kind outstretched hand is not enough to motivate the heart.

Answer (score 0):

One important point to this sort of question that was overlooked in this discussion is Election and Predestination. Most "humanist" don't take the interest or time to really study Christian Scripture and more importantly, if one is an unbeliever, will find most Christian beliefs foolishness because the revelation of Scripture is only spiritually discerned.

The fallacy of God being required to answer to man's sense of justice notwithstanding, the fallacies with questions relating to the justification of eternal torture are academic relative to the revealed truth of Scripture. God predestined His Elect from eternity and the reprobate will never believe and are condemned already.

The misconception is that we are here to make some sort of "decision for Christ" or, by others, that if we live a "virtuous life" that we will be judged well and permitted into Heaven. These are all false doctrine and the best we can do in this life "filthy rags" to God.

It's simple really, if your name appears in the Book of Life from before the foundation of the world then at some point God the Father will draw you to His Son and you will be saved out of this world. If not you will be condemned to hell. If that seems unfair to the OP or to the UN then, "who indeed are you - a mere human being - to talk back to God?". If this doesn't fit within the humanist's sense of judgement then that's too bad, this is God's Creation. It's all in the Scriptures and quite simple to those who are of the Elect and will always be foolishness to those who are perishing. God bless.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE! Please stick around - but you should check out [what we are](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1381/4188) and [what makes us different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/4188) than other sites. Because many of us have different beliefs, we take care to tell everybody where we're coming from (in this case, a Calvinistic framework). This keeps us from arguing about who is right and focusing on the teachings of various groups. It can take time to get used to it, but the links above can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3 questions:

**1. What's the justification of eternal torture in hell?**

The hell is the "eternal fire prepared for the devil and his angels". Now God give us the choice of follow God or the devil. Why someone that choose follow the devil (or choose do not follow God, in a biblical sense it's similar) will to heaven with the God followers? Is it fair? Now imagine a prison. It's not a nice place... but if you commit a crime, you (hopefully) will end in a prison. Hey, it's YOUR choice is there... You cannot blame the government or society (or even GOD) why **you are in a place that was not prepared originally for you...**

**2. Can the belief in hell be justified against the Convention in those countries?**

The God's Justice is **far** different of human justice. It's a topic for entire books, but you can notice by looking that gay marriage, abortion and another topics are approved in humam justice and not in the God justice...

**3. What is the meaning of eternal torture?**

Eternal torture is a eternal state of separation from God. Burning fire and torture are the lesser of your problems...