# Don't The Translation missed God's words?

Tags: bible

IMHO Bible Should not EVER be in any other language as a Bible , maybe as an explanation but not the main book , as it is God's word shouldn't we save it as it is? , beside this , it will be humans words and should not be hallowed as God's one.

Comment: And that language is...?

Comment: Aramic I think ? and we should learn it to read the Actual Bible ?

Comment: Welcome to the site! What exactly do you ask here? You are giving your opinion and that is not what this site is for here. I'd recommend you to spend some time getting to know how this site is different from others: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: thanks , Is the Translation the words of God too ?

Comment: Thanks , I'm asking about "Translated Bible is not God's words but an explanation for it" isn't it?

Comment: This is covered in the answer to [From a Fundamentalist standpoint, what does the phrase “Inspired, infallible, inerrant Word of God” mean?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/from-a-fundamentalist-standpoint-what-does-the-phrase-inspired-infallible-in). Short: Translations are not considered inspired, but we can have confidence that they accurately reflect the inspired Word.

Comment: Ok , I think I've understand , Bible inspired in its meaning not literally , so that humans write it whatever they found useful , am I right ?

Comment: Implicit in the question is the idea that it is impossible to convey the meaning of words in one language in the words of another language.  That idea would have to be substantiated and cannot just be assumed.  Indeed, for anyone to read the entire Bible, he would have to learn three languages other than his own.  From the very beginning, God's heart was for all people and all languages.  Placing a heavy burden on people all over the world to learn three new languages just to hear God's message seems quite harsh, especially when God created the languages in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't really ask a question, but let me try to answer the one you probably meant to ask anyway.

The trouble with insisting that the Bible be always in "the original language" is that there isn't a single original language for the Bible. The Old Testament was written in Hebrew - and old Hebrew at that, noticeably different from modern Hebrew. The New Testament was written in Greek, but also different from modern Greek. So there are at least two 'original' languages of the Bible.

But worse than that - the New Testament quotes the Old Testament many times, and does so in Greek. The quotes are no less part of scripture, so for them there are two different languages which are 'God's Word'. The fact that God approved of quoting the Old Testament Scriptures in Greek (not their original language) means that he must be OK with translations.

To make things even more complicated, Jesus almost certainly actually talked in Aramaic. So even the scriptures we have are translations of what God actually did really say. (We have no records of the original Aramaic, so it would be impossible to learn to read them) Once again this would tend to indicate that God is OK with translations. Paul, Peter and other Apostles probably wrote and spoke directly in Greek.

There is also a big theological reason for not forbidding translations. In the Christian view, the scriptures are 'inspired by God'.  This means God caused the Bible authors to write the message that he wanted using their own intellects and experience - he did not dictate to them his own exact words. That is not the same as (for example) the Islamic view of the Quran. In other words, the message of the Bible is in the meaning, not in the exact wording. God is all-powerful, and is certainly capable of making sure that any translations contain everything he needs to say.

So that's why your view about scripture is not the one that Christians believe. I hope that's helpful.

Comment: Well, the message of the Bible is certainly no less than its meaning, but it's okay to believe the wording is the result of the inspiration of God and the complete creative writing process of the authors too. It's one of those paradoxes we can't fully understand.

Comment: `the message of the Bible is in the meaning, not in the exact wording` that's is , Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible for anyone alive today to become fully fluent in the Biblical languages because there is no mothertongue speech community for them to learn those languages from. Many people do indeed try to learn the Biblical languages, with varying levels of success. Maybe some of them get to the stage where they can think in the Biblical languages, but even then it's only the top 0.001% of academic Christians. If they want to communicate it to anyone else they're going to have to translate it eventually. So do you want a translation by one person produced on the fly, or one produced by a large team of the world's best experts working together over several decades?

The Bible itself endorses Bible translations. The New Testament quotes the Greek translation of the Old Testament called the Septuagint. Nehemiah 8:8 describes the Levites explaining the Law "helping the people understand each passage". Although it doesn't specifically say they translated it, I believe this is what it is talking about, because the returned exiles spoke a different language than the Law had been written in.

Bible Translation is important because the Christian view of God is that he is a *relational* God - he loves to communicate with his people. A message that can't be understood is useless.

> Dear brothers and sisters, if I should come to you speaking in an unknown language, how would that help you? But if I bring you a revelation or some special knowledge or prophecy or teaching, that will be helpful. Even lifeless instruments like the flute or the harp must play the notes clearly, or no one will recognize the melody. And if the bugler doesn’t sound a clear call, how will the soldiers know they are being called to battle?
>
> It’s the same for you. If you speak to people in words they don’t understand, how will they know what you are saying? You might as well be talking into empty space.
>
> There are many different languages in the world, and every language has meaning. But if I don’t understand a language, I will be a foreigner to someone who speaks it, and the one who speaks it will be a foreigner to me. (1 Cor 14:6-11, NLT)

Comment: this is the first time a read bible in English , and its clearer than reading in Arabic [native] ! that illustrate what you said now , thanks very much.

Comment: Which Arabic translation have you read?

Comment: Don't say that there is several translations for the same language !! that makes thing worst for my question :(

Comment: Why does it make it worse? I think it actually makes it better - because every translation is imperfect and loses some detail, if you compare a few translations it will help you understand the original text.

Comment: Why can't we just found a perfect Bible to study ! now I know for sure that the current Bible is a mix of God's  perfect words With humans imperfect understand , and we can not separate them after all these years of MIXING :( Sorry for this conclusion .

Comment: Nothing is changed by translation. If you read the original Hebrew and Greek you will still have to work hard to get past your own imperfect understandings. What a translation does it make it easier for most people - unless you spend decades studying Hebrew and Greek you will be able understand a good translation better than you would the original texts.

Comment: But don't forget that not all translators translate directly from Hebrew and Greek , they mey translate a translation ! and that makes more and more mistakes , and some meanings will be lost .

Comment: While there are some translations from other intermediate languages, most English translations are from the original languages. The same is probably true in Arabic too. It's easy enough to check and avoid those translations if you want to.

Comment: So I have to search and ask before getting a Bible translated version, Thank you very much , you'v made it clear to me.

Comment: If you have any other questions about translations feel free to email me at curiousdannii@gmail.com! :)

Answer (score -2):

the bible is Gods word which the Holy spirit inspired men of God to write.thes no any problem in my opinion for a deferent translation in as much as the real meaning is not ultered.however,some peaple tries to change certain words to suites the selfish reasons but God in His own way always exposes such things.

Comment: thanks , translation is good to understand , but i'm asking about that it should not be considered as the word's of God too , but as "explanation" of it

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next is just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites), and
[What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience I've read the page and I think you mean this phrase `We care about Description not Prescription - more about Theology than "Truth"`